# Running Python script using pytest with arguments

Tags: python-2.7, pytest

I want to execute this script bellow using `pytest` with arguments that will be used by the same script.

This is the script name `test.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import os
import sys
import pytest
a = sys.argv[3] # the argument that we need
if len(a)== "0":
    sys.exit(1) 
def test_function():
    assert a == "g"
```

I want to run this script using `pytest` with an argument in this case 
the argument is: `g`.

I have tried the command `pytest -q test.py g`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: a = sys.argv[2] # the argument that we need  --------------> typing error

Comment: If you pass `g` the `pytest` considers it as a file parameter. Why do you want to pass test parameter like this?

Answer (score 0):

py.test scans for tests and runs them all. Passing the same arguments to each test file is a bad idea.

You can make your test 'self-running':

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pytest.main("-vv")
    # or pytest.main("-vv --cov --cov-report term-missing -s")
```

Then `chmod +x` your file and run it manually: `./test_something.py`